# Filtering paginated list items using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As part of a project to learn JavaScript, I'm currently building a website that has 50+ html list items that represent students, and writing a .js file to paginate all the items into pages of 10, as well as a search function that will filter which students show based on their names.

Here's an example of what these list items look like:

```
<li class="student-item cf">
    <div class="student-details">
        <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/94.jpg">
        <h3>lucy hall</h3>
        <span class="email">lucy.hall@example.com</span>
    </div>
    <div class="joined-details">
           <span class="date">Joined 09/11/16</span>
   </div>
</li>
```

The functions I've wrote to paginate the list items work well, however I'm struggling with implementing the search/filter functionality. Here's the code I've written for the search:

```
//------------------------SEARCH CONTENT OPEN--------------------------------//
//adding elements for the search bar
let searchBar = document.createElement('div.student-search');
let searchField = document.createElement('input');
$(searchField).attr('placeholder', 'Search for students...');
let searchButton = document.createElement('button');
$(searchButton).append('Search');

$('div.page-header').append(searchBar);
$(searchBar).append(searchField);
$(searchBar).append(searchButton);

// Variables for search functionality
let $filter = $(searchField).val().toLowerCase();
let $names = $($fullList).children('h3');

$(searchBar).on('keyup', (event) => {
    $($names).filter(() => {
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($filter) > -1);
    });
});
//--------------------SEARCH CONTENT CLOSE-------------------------------//
```

Adding this code to my website has no affect at all on the list items, how they paginate, or anything else on the website besides the search bar element being added to the page.

I think it may be related to a very odd error I'm receiving because of how I am showing and hiding the students. Here's how I'm doing that:

```
function showPage(list, page){
        for(var i = 0; i <= list.length; i+= 1){
            let currentStudent = list[i];
            let studentMin = page * 10;
            let studentMax = studentMin + 9;

            // Arrays for jQuery targets
            let showList = [];
            let hideList = [];

            if(i >= studentMin && i <= studentMax){
                showList.push(currentStudent);
            }else{
                hideList.push(currentStudent);
            }

            // adding hide to the old students and fading in the new students
            $(hideList).hide();
            $(showList).fadeIn();
        }
    }
```

At the line containing .hide(); I am getting this error:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

On whichever line of code I place the parent function that calls the showPage function, every line after that will not run. For example when I placed the parent function before my code to implement the search bar, the code wouldn't even create the variables or add the elements, but if I place the parent function at the end of everything, it runs, but isn't functional.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did my showPage function.

```
function showPage(list, page) {
    const startIndex = page * 9 - 9;
    const endIndex = page * 9;
    studentlist.innerHTML = "";
    let studentInfo = "";
    //If no results found during search
    if (list.length === 0) {
        studentInfo += `<p class="no-results">No Results Found</p>`;
    } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (i >= startIndex && i < endIndex) {
                studentInfo += `
         <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
               <img class="avatar" src="${list[i].picture.large}" alt="Profile Picture">
               <h3>${list[i].name.first} ${list[i].name.last}</h3>    
               <span class="email">${list[i].email}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
               <span class="date">Joined ${list[i].registered.date}</span>
          </div>
         </li>`;
            }
        }
    }
    studentlist.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", studentInfo);
}
```

and here is my [github repo](https://github.com/CodeLikeAGirl29/students-pagination)